# Is there a way to change the column names in user manager?

Tags: joomla-2.5, overrides, user, language

On [belgianpainsociety.org](http://belgianpainsociety.org) the registration of users is done through a extensive form by jomsocial. However, the first screen of the registration is the standard fields that Joomla needs for the user manager.

Now it asks for a name and a username. But in "name" some people type their last name, and others their first name. I want the form to ask people for their "full name" or "first name + last name" instead of just "name"...

Is this possible? If so, how?

UPDATE:

I created language overrides overrides:
[screenshot backend](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name1.png).

But in the registration form it hasn't changed:
[screenshot registration form](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name2.png).

The columns in the user manager haven't changed either:
[screenshot header user manager](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name3.png).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible using language overrides. In your admin area, go to **Extensions -> Language(s)**, and select **Overrides** in the left menu. Make sure you select the desired language in the "Filter" drop down.

[image: Language overrides in Joomla]

Click "New" to create a new override.

In the search field, type `COM_USERS_PROFILE_NAME`, and set "Search for" to "Constant". You should see something like this:

[image: Language overrides in Joomla]

Now you can change the text of both the label and the description to anything you want, e.g. "Full name", by clicking on the constant and then changing the text. Save, and you're done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks! I created the overrides:
[screenshot backend](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name1.png).

But in the registration form it hasn't changed:
[screenshot registration form](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name2.png).

The columns in the user manager haven't changed either:
[screenshot header user manager](http://belgianpainsociety.org/images/andere/name3.png).

Did I miss something?